# background position in a jquery code

Tags: jquery

within this code, what is the correct way to add background position to position the "play.png" image?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    $( ".audioplay img" ).click(function() {
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', $(this).attr('data-href'));
    if($(this).hasClass('playing')){
        $(this).attr("src","/wp-content/player/play.png"); <<<<<< BACKGROUND POSITION
        $('.audioplay img').removeClass("playing");
        audioElement.pause();
    }else{
        $('.audioplay img').removeClass("playing");
        $('.audioplay img').attr("src","/wp-content/player/play.png");
        $(this).attr("src","/wp-content/player/stop.png");
        $(this).addClass("playing");
        audioElement.play();
    }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding css via juqery

```
$(this).css('background-position', '10px 10px');
```

and in case you want to remove bg position

```
$(this).css('background-position', '');
```

Comment: click on the tick near my answer & make it green ..accept it as answer...& earn reputation :)